# ListView spacing between items/ordering by groups

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

How do I make some spacing between some items in my listView? I have a program, that lists all files in their respective folders, but now the list looks like:

```
---FolderName1---
fileName1
fileName2
fileName3
---FolderName2---
fileName1
fileName2
```

And so on...

The view mode I am using is List, and I would like to have some spacing where the folder names are, but I would like to avoid having to add another empty line, just to have a bit of space between the last file name and the folder name, and the first file. How do I achieve that?

```
for (int i = 0; i < folderNum; i++)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(folderNum[i].Name);
    for (int j = 0; j < fileNum; j++)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(fileNum[j].Name);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You can assign a different font to each item but the height will always be the same..

Comment: What if I use a different view mode? Is there a way to make some sort of groups, where the group name is the folder name or something like that?

Comment: You can use `View=Details` and create Groups. They are taller but I found no way to set their Font etc..

Comment: Okay, how exactly do I do this? I do not want any columns or pictures in the groups. I edited the question with some pseudocode. There should be something in the outer for loop to make the folder names into groups, but I do not know what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `View=Details` and create `Groups`. They are taller but unfortunately I found no way to set their `Font` etc..

You can add the `Groups` while you add the `Items` or before or later. You can add more `Groups`or change to which an item belongs at any time. You can also remove a `Group`; in that case all its Items get move to the `'default' Group`.

Here is an example:

[image]

Prepare a few data:

```
string root = @"D:\scrape\patterns";
string mask = "*10*";
List<string> folders = Directory.GetDirectories(root).ToList();
List<string> files = Directory.GetFiles(root, mask, SearchOption.AllDirectories).ToList();
```

Prepare the `ListView`:

```
listView1.View = View.Details;
listView1.Columns.Add("Png Files");
```

Now add `Groups`:

```
    // 1st group: add root search folder..:
    listView1.Groups.Add(root,root);
    // .. and all 1st level nested folders as more (possible) groups:
    foreach (string f in folders) listView1.Groups.Add(f, f);
```

Finally insert `Items`:

```
    // insert items with groups:
    foreach (string f in files)
    {
        string key = Path.GetDirectoryName(f);
        string text = Path.GetFileName(f);
        var lvi = listView1.Items.Add(text);
        lvi.Group = listView1.Groups[key];
    }
```

Note that you can change the `Group` an `Item` belongs to at any time..:

```
listView2.Items[2].Group = listView2.Groups[1];
```

A few notes:

- If you look closely you can see that the `Item` I moved was assigned to a `Group` which was empty before. Those are not displayed at all.
- Any `Item` without a `Group` is added to a `Group "default"`, which is displayed at the top. You can't change the name, so it is best to create one of your own and assign 'ungrouped' items to it. I used the name of the search root for this.
- I know of no way to style the groups beyond `HeaderText` and `HeaderAlignment`; there seem to be no properties nor are they drawn in any of the `DrawXXX` events. There are strangley incomplete hints at doing it in an [DrawVisualStyleElementListViewGroup1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.visualstyles.visualstyleelement.listview.group(v=vs.110).aspx) event or function but I couldn't find out how to use it..

Comment: Thank you, this works like a charm. I wish there was more documentation on the different view modes of the list.